# NodeJS split Sign.sign() output into multiple line

Tags: node.js, openssl, cryptography, digital-signature

I'm using `Sign.sign()` to create a signature of a file using the following code:

```js
const sign = () => {
  const fData = fs.readFileSync("test.txt");
  const sign = crypto.createSign("SHA256");
  sign.update(fData);
  const b64 = sign.sign(
    {
      key: getPrivateKey(),
      passphrase: "pass",
    },
    "base64"
  );
  fs.writeFileSync("license.txt.sign.base64", b64);
};
```

The output is technically identical to the one I created with the openssl command, but the openssl command split the output into multiple lines.
I don't think this should be a problem, but when I try to verify the signature using a C# application (in this case I use the binary version of the signature instead of the base64 version), I get **valid from the openssl signature** and **invalid from the JS signature**.

Thus I came to the conclusion that the issue must the that one is split into multiple lines, while the other is just one line. I also noticed, that openssl added an empty new line at the end of the file, which might also be the cause of my problems.

This is the version generated by my JS code:

```
NPwlAtID6t+3GVJeiWvprZUrAKkQsxeA6Sv0Fb6+xCkkgaoFdxOwufc4Bb7ZWX3Ym+S6A2ZxmWNgclC8cr80iUHLlcNxrOKoe6A3TS/qdND0IwV/jfxbkkRL734Ko7roTQoNpMDJYK4H3fyVSp/qLOYPXeuIIjulTY0StfDf8Azbf6Uwq8piG5QxkbHTIdRMVeR+UDQd1M7HxVATxbDQhvbDyyRd3zMaMUOmFXM0Ow60s9wMlJTCVpTIiu66PfekQah0oEhWpUAf6qrcVWK10mEg49YCHCYYFw441kOPhRAZndtp3ZHn+BtgQ/HZNM47JRRQs8QGwmkCNCYfEjI8Lg==
```

This is the version generated by openssl:

```
NPwlAtID6t+3GVJeiWvprZUrAKkQsxeA6Sv0Fb6+xCkkgaoFdxOwufc4Bb7ZWX3Y
m+S6A2ZxmWNgclC8cr80iUHLlcNxrOKoe6A3TS/qdND0IwV/jfxbkkRL734Ko7ro
TQoNpMDJYK4H3fyVSp/qLOYPXeuIIjulTY0StfDf8Azbf6Uwq8piG5QxkbHTIdRM
VeR+UDQd1M7HxVATxbDQhvbDyyRd3zMaMUOmFXM0Ow60s9wMlJTCVpTIiu66Pfek
Qah0oEhWpUAf6qrcVWK10mEg49YCHCYYFw441kOPhRAZndtp3ZHn+BtgQ/HZNM47
JRRQs8QGwmkCNCYfEjI8Lg==
```

These are the commands used to create the openssl signature:

```
openssl dgst -sha256 -sign priv_key -out test.txt.sign test.txt
openssl base64 -in test.txt.sign -out test.txt.sign.base64
```

Thanks to
President @James K. Polk for making me aware that the validation code is just as important. I have attached it below:

```cs
var key = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Entwicklung\NodeJS\test-crypto\my_rsa.pem");
var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
rsa.ImportCspBlob(key);
var signature = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Entwicklung\NodeJS\test-crypto\test.txt.sign");
var data = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Entwicklung\NodeJS\test-crypto\test.txt");
var sha256 = new SHA256Managed();
var hash = sha256.ComputeHash(data);
var result = rsa.VerifyHash(hash, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA256"), signature);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: The code used to verify the signature is just as important to this issue.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk you're right. I've attached it now. Oh I think I should also mention that I'm using .Net Framework version 4.8

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem: The signatures generated by the NodeJS code (whether binary or Base64 encoded) can be verified with the C# code for me. Since it is the deterministic PKCS#1 v1.5 signature, a comparison is possible. If your problem persists, you should post a test key pair (at least a test private key), including plaintext and signature that is not verifiable.

Comment: @Topaco I have created a repository that contains all the relevant files, including the two programs. https://github.com/m-radmacher/License-Test
But I also noticed that now my NodeJS code is NOT generating a similar signature, so the problem now seems to be figuring out how to generate a valid signature in NodeJs. Currently I get this error when this error when trying to verify the generated signature with openssl
Verification failure
rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_1:invalid padding:../crypto/rsa/rsa_pk1.c:75

Comment: In the NodeJS code, the `'binary'` encoded signature is corrupted by an implicit UTF-8 encoding during saving. As fix the following change is needed: `fs.writeFileSync("test.txt.sign", signature, { encoding: 'binary' })` (this has no effect for the `'base64'` encoded signature, so no distinction is required here).

Comment: Alternatively, in `sign.sign()` the specification of the encoding, i.e. the second parameter is to be removed, so that the signature is returned as buffer. The encoding is then performed with: `fs.writeFileSync("test.txt.sign", base64 ? signature.toString('base64') : signature)`.

Comment: With these changes, your code works and the verification of the raw signature with the C# code is successful.